# How can I anonymize outgoing AzureAD/B2C Tenant ID?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

Assume I purchase a multitenant application (HR software) located in Azure AD Tenant 1.  (synonymous to a resource forest).

I also purchase a health application owned by a different company located in Azure Tenant 2.

I don't own administrative rights to Tenant 1 nor 2.

**Question 1**

- As the administrator of an Office 365/AzureAD forest, how can I allow users to log into to those tenants, but prevent the correlation of their user IDs between applications I don't own?

In other words, I don't want a hacker, or other entity to collude and "join" data between application 1 and application 2.

The values I'm concerned about include:

```
TenantIdenfifiers
http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid:
iss:

UserIdentifiers
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: 
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn: 
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier:
http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier: 
name
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname: 
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname:
```

**Question 2**

- What other values besides the ones listed above should I be concerned about colluding to reconstruct an anonymized user?  (e.g. msft graph, office APIs, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The unique identifier of the user along with the tenant are always passed in regular Azure AD. You can't really do anything about it.

Those attributes are needed by applications. The tenant id is used to know what your subscription is, what data you have access to etc. The user object id can be used to identify the user, since the user principal name can be changed.

But your tenant's users can't log in to *those tenants* without them being added as guests there, and them accepting it.

Typically those apps you buy a subscription for are multi-tenant, so your tenant admin must allow sign-in to that app. After that is done your tenant's users can sign in there. In this case they are still signing in to your tenant, but the app has been given permissions in your tenant through the service principal created for it.

As for Azure AD B2C, you can affect what claims are given to the applications. But the gotcha is of course that B2C does not support multi-tenant applications. [Not yet](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9849063-aadb2c-how-to-on-multi-tenant-applications-based) at least. Later we might be able to also allow Azure AD authentication in B2C. But even then the application owner controls the claims and the application.